# Tridion Broker db and IIS

Tags: tridion, tridion-content-delivery

I am currently using Tridion 5.3.After pages are published from Tridion CM side to Broker db.
How should be IIS configured to point to the pages in DB like we do for file system.

Comment: This question is missing any kind of research effort and the answer can only be something like read the documentation or follow a training.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to start with this topic from the documentation (login required):
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_72627979491D47A78F1735CB76DF7AA4

The documentation is for Tridion 2011 SP1, but the same high-level concepts apply for Tridion 5.3. But if you can, definitely consider looking up the corresponding topic in the PDFs that came with your Tridion installation.